# Where do I find my unsaved code in visual studio code IDE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I wrote some code in visual studio. suddenly my system got hanged. I shut down forcefully.When I open my all codes are removed.

Where Can I find that code?

Comment: I don't know how VS handles those sort of files, but if VS is not offering it to you as a "do you want to recover these files" dialog, then it's likely they're gone

Comment: I don't know how to recover my codes. Please help me out

Comment: You will likely find those in a cache directory under your profile. Probably directory called just cache or maybe CacheData.

Comment: I am using ubuntu OS. Where can I find that?